# Preserve the insert order in a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a PHP page used by an Ajax call that I want to return an ordered list of items as JSON. However whichever field I use in the query's 'order by' clause the array is always ordered by its key, the ID field.

Is there a way to preserve the insert order of each item in the PHP array?

This is the code that generates the JSON array:

```
$Soggetti = array();
while($row = $db->fetch_array($query))
{
    $Soggetti[$row['ID']] = array();
    $Soggetti[$row['ID']]['Denominazione'] = $row['Denominazione'];
    $Soggetti[$row['ID']]['Indirizzo'] =   $row['Indirizzo'].','.$row['Comune'].', '.$row['Provincia'];
    $Soggetti[$row['ID']]['Superficie'] = $row['Superficie'];
    $Soggetti[$row['ID']]['Lat'] = $row['Lat'];
    $Soggetti[$row['ID']]['Lng'] = $row['Lng'];
    $Soggetti[$row['ID']]['Tipologia'] = $row['Tipologia'];
    $Soggetti[$row['ID']]['CodiceIscrizione'] = $row['CodiceIscrizione'];
    $Soggetti[$row['ID']]['Visitato'] = intval($row['Visitato']);
}
echo json_encode($Soggetti)
```

Comment: I'm having trouble reproducing the error; the JSON reflects the order the records were inserted into the `$Soggetti` array. Have you tried echoing the value of `$row['ID']` inside your loop?

Comment: If your ID column is numerical, eg. int, then Mike Brant's answer should give you the correct result. However if you need to have the array indexed with a numerical ID then there's no way to get the array to be ordered in any other way than by the ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are building a 2 dimensional array with the key on first dimension being the id.  Assuming `id` is numeric you will end up with nested objects in JSON, with the key of top level being the numerical id values. The problem here being that object properties have no guarantee of order.

To get the order of the query results, simply build a 1-D array inside your result set loop like this:

```
$tempArray = array();
$tempArray['ID'] = $row['ID'];
$tempArray['Denominazione'] = $row['Denominazione'];
$tempArray['Indirizzo'] = $row['Indirizzo'].','.$row['Comune'].', '.$row['Provincia'];
$tempArray['Superficie'] = $row['Superficie'];
$tempArray['Lat'] = $row['Lat'];
$tempArray['Lng'] = $row['Lng'];
$tempArray['Tipologia'] = $row['Tipologia'];
$tempArray['CodiceIscrizione'] = $row['CodiceIscrizione'];
$tempArray['Visitato'] = intval($row['Visitato']);
$Soggetti[] = $tempArray;
```

The will encode to JSON as an array of objects with the array numerically indexed from 0 based on order in result set.

Comment: No, [the resultant array is ordered by the order of insertion](http://3v4l.org/c0EdP).

Comment: @amphetamachine Yes, but the order of insertion is determined directly from the ordering of the result set.

Comment: @amphetamachine You example link only shows PHP implications of buidling 2-D array.  Take it the next step further and serialize to JSON and then deserialize and iterate in javascript.  That is when the problem becomes apparent.  You will get different behavior between different browser client in terms of how they iterate of numerically-named object properties.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem lies in where the JSON is interpreted, in the client, you can use this syntax to return a JSON **array** (enclosed in `[]`) instead of a JSON **object** (enclosed in `{}`).

```
echo json_encode(array_values($Soggetti));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem may lie in your mysql query, try:

```
select * from table_name order by ID asc
```

Comment: the query is ok, also cheched in php admin e the order is correct, i digged more into the issue, the array returned from the page stille have the right order. It get changed when the json string is transformed into javascript variable,  var json = response.responseJSON;

Comment: In what way does the order change?

Comment: the array is ordered by the key, the value of $row['ID'] , the ajax call is made with prototype library

Answer (score 0):

You need an `ORDER BY` clause of your MySQL statement.

In this case you want to order by your id, and in ascending order, so;

```
SELECT * from your_table ORDER BY id ASC
```

Reference: [MySQL Sorting](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html)